# How do you prove this vector space $M_{2X2}$ with direct sum $\oplus$ and $\otimes $ involved?

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

Consider $M_{2X2}$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \oplus \begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{pmatrix}=$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} ae & bf \\ cg & dh \end{pmatrix}$$
And constant k times matrix:

$K \otimes \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}=$ $\begin{pmatrix} a^k & b^k \\ c^k & d^k \end{pmatrix}$
Show that it is a vector space.

I tried by myself to prove the 8 properties to validate the vector space.
How does it work when direct sum symbol gets involved with vector spaces? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "direct sum" is a red herring. Since $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ work on each position of the $2×2$ matrix separately, we might as well only consider one such position:
$$a\oplus b=ab\qquad k\otimes a=a^k$$
It is clear that this "reduced" structure is also a vector space, with identity $1$ and inverse $1/a$, which means that the original structure is also a vector space.

Note that all of the matrix entries must be positive for the given structure to be a vector space, but this has not explicitly been written in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Comment: It’s *not* clear that this reduced structure is a vector space. What’s the additive inverse of zero?

Comment: @PersonX Perhaps it was implied in the question, but yes, it should have read "matrices with _nonzero_ entries".

Comment: You also have to be careful about negative entries. How are you defining $1/2 \otimes (-1)$?

Comment: @PersonX Edited again.

Comment: Thank you. You re absolutely right.